# Converting columns from float datatype to categorical datatype using binning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

I wish to convert a data frame consisting of two columns.

Here is the sample df:

Output:

```
df:

    cost      numbers   
1    360        23

2    120        35

3    2000       49
```

Both columns are float and I wish to convert them to categorical using binning.
I wish to create the following bins for each column when converting to categorical.

Bins for the numbers : 18-24,  25-44,  45-65,  66-92

Bins for cost column: >=1000, <1000

Finally, I want to not create a new column but just convert the column without creating a new one.
Here is my attempted code at this:

```
def PreprocessDataframe(df):
 
     #use binning to convert age and budget to categorical columns
    df['numbers'] = pd.cut(df['numbers'], bins=[18, 24, 25, 44, 45, 65, 66, 92])
    df['cost'] = pd.cut(df['cost'], bins=['=>1000', '<1000'])
    
    return df
```

I understand how to convert the "numbers" column but I am having trouble with the "cost" one.
Help would be nice on how to solve this.
Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `bins=[18, 24, 25, 44, 45, 65, 66, 92]`, this is going to generate bins for 18-24, 24-25, 25-44, 44-45, etc... and you don't need the ones for 24-25, 44-45...

By default, the bins are from the first value (not incusive) to the last value inclusive.

So, for `numbers`, you could use instead `bins=[17, 24, 44, 65, 92]` (note the `17` at the first position, so 18 is included).

The optional parameter `label` allows to choose labels for the bins.

```
df['numbers'] = pd.cut(df['numbers'], bins=[17, 24, 44, 65, 92], labels=['18-24', '25-44', '45-65', '66-92'])
df['cost'] = pd.cut(df['cost'], bins=[0, 999.99, df['cost'].max()], labels=['<1000', '=>1000'])

print(df)

>>> df
     cost numbers
0   <1000   18-24
1   <1000   25-44
2  =>1000   45-65
```

Comment: Hi thanks for te reply... I want the number column figures to look like this  18-24, 25-44, 45-65, 66-92 Any recommendation on how to do that?